# What Java GUI library IDEA IntelliJ uses?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm looking for Java GUI library especially on Mac OS X.

I checked SWT/JFace, and I tested eclipse and RCP which is customized eclipse as an example. I also checked SWING, and for the example I tested NetBeans.

I found that Jetbrains tools such as IDEA ntelliJ, RubyMine, and PyCharm seem to fit my needs, but I'm not sure what GUI tools they are using.

They don't seem like a RCP application as I see no OSGi libraries, and the GUI seems to be a little bit different from SWING.

What Java GUI library  IDEA IntelliJ uses? Further more, what options do I have when I make GUI program on Mac OS X using Java other than SWT/JFace and SWING?

Comment: Check this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/06/11/inside-darcula-look-and-feel-an-interview-with-konstantin-bulenkov/

Within the product, everything users see and interact with is my responsibility. I spend most of my time creating and tuning Swing UI components, improving performance and making our IDEs clean and intuitive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses Swing. I know because you can set those old school look and feels Swing ships with.

You could also use JavaFX.